# android view not updated from another class and another thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, view

I am trying to update TextView in an activity, the method which updates the view is in the main activity (normal situation), but calling this method is from another class (and another thread).

This is the method which updates the view, this method is in the main activity,
 (please note that all logs are printed correctly and in the correct order):

```
    public void getDataFromFiles() {
    String new_text = JsonReader.readTextData(dataName,activityName, this);
    Log.i("Loading", "loaded text " + new_text  );
    if (new_text != null) {
        TextView introText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.loading_introTxt);
        introText.setText(new_text);
    }

}
```

This is where it is called from another class called LoadingThread, and it has reference (loadingActivity) :

```
            activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Log.i("LoadingThread", "Will update loading screen");
                loadingActivity.getDataFromFiles();

            }
        });
```

Also note how the LoadingThread class is called from main activity

```
    LoadingThread loadingThread = LoadingThread.getInstance(this);
    Thread thread = new Thread(loadingThread);
    loadingThread.setActivity(this);
    thread.start();
```

so this is the flow: 
the main activity starts the LoadingThread which then after that call a method in the main activity again which is supposed to update the view, but this does not happen, but when closing the app and reopening it again, the updates are there then.

Comment: You are running the update on the UI thread so that is not the problem. Try adding introText.invalidate(); after setting the text in getDataFromFiles().

Comment: Can you try keeping the reference of the loading_introTxt in the activity and see if it helps ?

Comment: @juan no it did not work unfortunately

Comment: @SagarWaghmare I printed in the log introText.getText(), and it changing correctly, one more thing I noticed, is that when I run the application after removing it from recent activities it works properly, but if I pressed back and reopened it, it does not update properly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem, it was in

```
LoadingThread loadingThread = LoadingThread.getInstance(this);
Thread thread = new Thread(loadingThread);
loadingThread.setActivity(this);
```

while getInstance() is:

```
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new LoadingThread();
        instance.loadingActivity = loadingActivity;

    }
    return instance;
```

when closing and reopening the app, the instance is not null so returning the previous activity which is not here any more because the reference on loading activity was not updated, so I changed it like that

```
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new LoadingThread();
    }
    instance.loadingActivity = loadingActivity;
    return instance;
```

and now it works!